# I have written code for custom hook but everytime I bring boolean toggles from true to false

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-hooks

code for customhook

```
import { useState , useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { onAuthStateChanged , getAuth} from "firebase/auth";

export const useAuthStatus = () => {
    const [loggedIn , setLoggedIn] = useState(false)
    const [checkingStatus , setCheckingStatus] = useState(true)
    const isMounted = useRef(true)
    useEffect(() => {
        if(isMounted){
            const auth = getAuth()
            onAuthStateChanged(auth , (user) => {
                if(user){
                    setLoggedIn(true)
                }
                setCheckingStatus(false)
            })
        }
        return () =>{
            isMounted.current = false
        }
    }, [isMounted])
  return {loggedIn , checkingStatus}
   
}
```

imported to

```
import {Navigate , Outlet} from 'react-router-dom'
import  {useAuthStatus}  from '../hooks/useAuthStatus'

const PrivateRoute = () => {
const {loggedIn , checkingStatus} = useAuthStatus()  
  if(checkingStatus){
    <h3>Loading...</h3>
  }
  return loggedIn?  console.log('hoax') : console.log('not Hoax');
  
}
```

Here at first I checked for if user has logged in from firebase , If yes we go to profile page or go to log-in page but, at first it goes to profile page than immidietly switches to log-in page, when I used console log(loggedIn)at first it shows true than suddenly toggkes to false

Comment: Change `if(isMounted){` to `if(isMounted.current){` because `isMounted` is a object, and the condition is always truthy. In addition move `isMounted.current = false` out of the return, since the returned function would only run when the component unmounts.

Comment: That sounds like an answer @OriDrori :)